# transform array of objects into array of pointers to unique objects

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, duplicates

I am trying to transform an array of objects into an array of object pointers, where the pointers point to elements of an array which contains all unique objects of the first array.

The objects I am using are not cheap to copy as they involve buffer allocation and buffer copying. They are, however, cheap to move.

Example:
The array

[G,F,E,G,E,G]

should be transformed into a unique object array
U = [E,F,G] and a pointer array
P = [&U[2], &U[1], &U[0], &U[2], &U[0], &U[2]]

I am currently using the following code to achieve this:

```
int N; // 50 Millions and more
std::vector<MyObj> objarray; // N elements
std::vector<MyObj*> ptrarray; // N elements
...
std::vector<MyObj> tmp(objarray.begin(), objarray.end());

std::sort(objarray.begin(), objarray.end());
auto unique_end = std::unique(objarray.begin(), objarray.end());

// now, [objarray.begin(), unique_end) contains all unique objects

std::map<MyObj, int> indexmap;

// save index for each unique object
int index = 0;
for(auto it = objarray.begin(); it != uniqueend; it++){
    indexmap[*it] = index;
    index++;
}

//for each object in original array, look up index in unique object array and save the pointer
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    ptrarray[i] = &objarray[indexmap[tmp[i]]];
```

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this, possibly without creating a copy of the original array since object copies are expensive?

Comment: Are they cheap to *move*?  And that code looks wrong, as it sorts and eliminates before tracking where they came from.  Plus it fails to trim off the end of the array after eliminating duplicates.

Comment: Yes, they are cheap to move. I added this information to the post. The trimming is not shown in the code. It happens before filling the ptrarray.

Comment: Another issue is you're storing pointers to elements within the vector.  If that vector is resized in any way, those pointers can be invalidated.  For example: `ptrarray[i] = &objarray[indexmap[tmp[i]]];`

Comment: @Abator Abetor, using the vector index (position) of each object as _identifier_ is worrying for me ..

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am aware of this. objarray does not change after setting the pointers. The lifetime of ptrarray and objarray are identical, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct r {
  std::vector<MyObj> objects;
  std::vector<MyObj*> ptrs;
};

r func( std::vector<MyObj> objarray ) {

  // makes a vector containing {0, 1, 2, 3, ..., N-1}
  auto make_index_buffer = [&]{
    std::vector<std::size_t> r;
    r.reserve(objarray.size());
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < objarray.size(); ++i)
      r.push_back( i );
    return r;
  };

  // build a buffer of unique element indexes:
  auto uniques = make_index_buffer();

  // compares indexes by their object: 
  auto index_less = [&](auto lhs, auto rhs) { return objarray[lhs]<objarray[rhs]; };
  auto index_equal = [&](auto lhs, auto rhs) { return objarray[lhs]==objarray[rhs]; };

  std::sort( uniques.begin(), uniques.end(), index_less );
  uniques.erase( std::unique( uniques.begin(), uniques.end(), index_equal ), uniques.end() );

  // build table of index to unique index:
  std::map<std::size_t, std::size_t, index_less> table;
  for (std::size_t& i : uniques)
    table[i] = &i-uniques.data();

  // list of index to unique index for each element:
  auto indexes = make_index_buffer();

  // make indexes unique:
  for (std::size_t& i:indexes)
    i = table[i];

  // after this, table will be invalidated.  Clear it first:
  table = {};

  // build unique object list:
  std::vector<MyObj> objects;
  objects.reserve( uniques.size() );
  for (std::size_t i : uniques)
    objects.push_back( std::move(objarray[i]) );

  // build pointer objects:
  std::vector<MyObj*> ptrarray; // N elements
  ptrarray.reserve( indexes.size() );
  for (std::size_t i : indexes)
    ptrarray.push_back( std::addressof( objects[i] ) );

  return {std::move(objects), std::move(ptrarray)};
}
```

This does exactly N moves of `MyObj`, where N is the number of unique `MyObj` in your original vector.

Yours did M lg M moves of `MyObj`, and N copies, where M is the number of objects and N is the number of unique objects.

Mine does some allocation (of size_ts) you can probably clean up, but that would make it a bit less clear.

Comment: I guess you built your code still on pointer vector to minimize the change for clarity .. wouldn't it be more `suitable!` to introduce a struct with and int representing the object absolute position as well as its object pointer?

Comment: There is still a small bug in your code. the lambda for std::unique should test for equivalency, not less than. Nonetheless, great work. thank you.

Comment: @AbatorAbetor Fixed.  Price I pay for not compiling and running.

Comment: @MohammadKanan Perhaps.  It will depend on what the uses are and how carefully lifetime is measured.  A pointer-to-vector and offset has different invalidation problems than a pointer-to-element.  You could even go with the aliasing ctor of shared pointer and store the vector of elements in a shared ptr.